# Sanitizing password_hash() strings

Tags: php, regex, bcrypt, password-encryption

I'd like some help coming up with a safe and future-forward way to sanitize hash strings which were originally generated by `password_hash()`.

`password_hash()` will be implemented on my system with the default algorithm PASSWORD_DEFAULT integer, which would be `bcrypt()` encryption, however it can change in the future versions of PHP.

None of the manual pages I've read explicitly state what characters may be generated by this algorithm.

Can anyone suggest a minimum amount of sanitizing that would work? Maybe...

```
filter_var( $hashedPassword, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
```

or

```
preg_replace( '/^[a-zA-Z0-9-\$\=]*$/', '', $hashedPassword );
```

If you have something specific for bcrypt, but not necessarily whatever PHP changes to in the future and I have to update my regex string in the future, well that's the breaks, let me know and I'll consider it.

Thanks for any help.

P.S. If you wonder why bother sanitize them, well because it's being passed around a bit across two systems because of some password migration we're doing from one system to another and it just feels dirty not sanitizing my function's input when coming from another system :)

Comment: *Sanitising* for use where / in what?

Comment: Just before using it for password_verify(). Or should I just implicitly trust it?

Comment: Why would you need to alter the hash at all? One *sanitises* a string to make it safe to use in a system. What is there to make safe here? Also, altering the hash would ultimately make it fail verification.

Comment: I don't want to alter the hash, I want to protect one system from another and ensure that nothing compromises password_verify() unless it auto-magically protects itself when handling input? System A has a stored pass. Page 1 accepts a password. System B compares the stored pass and input pass, then stores it itself. Obviously sanitizing something and running verify would fail, which is OK, better safe than.

Comment: What **exactly** do you think are the safety / security concerns with using `password_verify()` that you believe requires some sort of sanitising?

Comment: If System B “stores” _any_ kind of data, the necessary treatment for the _context_ of that storing mechanism has to be applied – but this has _nothing_ whatsoever to do with whether that data is a hashed password, or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `password_hash()` is basically just a nicer implementation of the `crypt()` function, using the Blowfish algorithm by default:

```
crypt('somepassword', '$2y$10$randomlygeneratedsalt$');
```

The `crypt()` function returns a string that looks like this:

```
$2y$10$randomlygeneratedsalte2uDLvp1Ii2e./U9C8sBjqp8I90dH6hi
```

It uses `$` delimiters to separate the segments:

1. Algorithm
2. Cost
3. Salt/hash combination

From the [documentation](http://php.net/crypt) (emphasis is mine):

> [...] Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: **"$2a$", "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z".** [...] The two digit cost parameter [...] must be in range 04-31 [...]

The hash itself is a base64 encoded string using `.` and `/` as the two last characters.

In other words, a hash generated by `password_hash()` contains:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9$/.]
```

And it is 60 characters long.

I do not know why you would want to sanitize it (a hash should never be modified, so there should not be anything to sanitize), but something like this should work:

```
$sanitized = filter_var($hash, FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => function($hash) {
    return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9$\/.]/', '', $hash);
}]);
```